# How to reference file correctly in filevar option in SAS?

Tags: sas

Here is a simple code to read two files

```
filename one "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SAS\nbExce\ch1\1-12 one.txt" ; 
filename two "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SAS\nbExce\ch1\1-12 two.txt" ; 

data test ; 
input extfile $ ; 
infile dummy filevar=extfile end=last ;
do until (last) ;
input name $ score ;
output ;
end ;
datalines ;
one
two
;
run ; 

proc  print ;
run ;
```

Why do I get this error ? How can I improve my file references ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to file assigned using a filename statement in the filevar. Use the full path to the files.

```
data test;
 infile datalines dsd; 
 length extfile $128;
 input extfile $; 
 infile dummy filevar=extfile end=last;
 do until (last);
  input name $ score;
  output;
 end;
datalines;
"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SAS\nbExce\ch1\1-12 one.txt"
"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SAS\nbExce\ch1\1-12 two.txt"
;
run;
```

Comment: +1 thank you . I tried this. But it does not work because file name contains blank . However this works  `1-12one.txt` . How can I make `1-12 one.txt` work ?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't test it with spaces. I modified it to work with spaces in the filename by adding an infile statement for the datalines with DSD options and added quotes around the filenames.